# Highlight active links

Tags: html, css

I am creating a sidebar menu and having a problem highlighting the active link - I would like the text of the highlighted link to be white instead of the grey.

Appreciate the support.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> Post Blog</i></a></li>
    <li><a Href="/menu.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> Post Blog</i></a></li>
    <li><a Href="/calendar.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> Post Blog</i></a></li>
    <li><a Href="/shop.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> Post Blog</i></a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
position: fixed;
width: 180px;
margin-left: -180px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);  
}
#nav ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav li a:link, li a:visited{
display: block;
padding: 15px 15px;
border-left: 8px solid #005b86;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333333;  
}
#nav li a:hover{
background-color: #005b86;
color: #FFF;
}
#nav .active{
background-color: #005b86;
color: #FFF;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is to try to get your style to override the other styles that have `color` specified.

I would suggest reading up on css specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Try

```
#nav li.active a:link{
  background-color: #005b86;
  color: #FFF;    
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/9drxzat5/

Comment: Apparently your code works on Chrome but not Safari. I have cleared cache and cookies.

Comment: you're going to have to use developer tools for safari to try to figure it out. good luck man.

Comment: So it works in the beginning but then turns into a visited link and the text turns grey.

Comment: Add the same class again but use a:visited instead of a:link